# Request to merge or synonym tags: [mongo] and [mongodb]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Please merge or synonym these tags:

- [mongo](https://serverfault.com/tags/mongo)
- [mongodb](https://serverfault.com/tags/mongodb)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've merged them:

`mongo` was removed from 9 questions, `mongodb` was added to 1 question. A tag synonym mapping mongo → mongodb has been created.